# Bluetooth appears "Permanently" not available - macOS 10.15

Tags: macos, bluetooth, catalina

For some reason after an "upgrade" to 10.15 Catalina, Bluetooth appears to be "Permanently" not available.

How can I diagnose which “a device” to connect to get Bluetooth to work ?

Upgraded to 10.15.2 but no better.

[image: bluetooth wireless settings]

[image: taskbar]

[image: not available]

[image: os version and hardware]

Any suggestions?  Does this have anything to do with Bluetooth pan internet sharing?

[image]

[image: bluetooth demon]

[image: bluetooth not available]

[image: bluetooth plist]

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT210642#macos1014 10.15.1 doesnt fix this if it were a bug

Comment: I just updated to MacOS 10.15.2 and still I'm seeing the same problem.

Comment: Try safe boot to see if it works there or is it third party interference.

Comment: ankii, interesting idea (SAFE BOOT) I just tried this and it still shows the same problem... I did notice that there is a process called "bluetoothd" (bluetooth demon) running in the Activity Monitor? In the "system preferences" the only way I'm able to access bluetooth is through the "network" and it shows that the connection "Bluetooth PAN" is not connected?

Comment: It maybe that there is some problem in /Library/Prefreferences/ and unpairing and forgetting any device that has been connected in the past. You can do this by clicking the Bluetooth icon on the top bar of your screen while holding down the Alt and Shift keys. When you see the Debug menu, first click on Remove All Devices, followed by Reset Bluetooth Module. Once you're up and running again, see if your Bluetooth works?

Comment: # --- Bluetooth Status

    Power                : Off
    MAC Address          : None
    Discoverable         : No
    Connectable          : No
    Scanning             : No
    Devices              : 0 (paired=0 cloud=0 connected=0)

Comment: I did all that and was able to connect it with iPhone.

Comment: https://www.howtoisolve.com/alternate-way-to-solve-error-bluetooth-not-available-on-mac-solved/#Solution_6_Reset_Bluetooth_Module This is a recent article. Please try them all, SMC is my hope.

Answer (score 0):

macOS Catalina Version 10.15.6 (19G73) seems to have "fixed" some of the problem but not all of it...

The MacOS "Console" System Log still has some error messages however the bluetooth connection does show up in networking.

**bluetoothhd : deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.server.bluetooth**

Here is what the screen shot of the system log files look like if you search for "bluetooth"

[image]

the suspicion is that this is a hardware to OS "bridge bug" that is specific to MacBook Pro's?  For example... my system with...

```
Hardware Overview:

  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,3
  Processor Name:   Quad-Core Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.8 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
  Memory:   16 GB
  Boot ROM Version: 162.0.0.0.0
  SMC Version (system): 2.19f12
```

Comment: You have an issue with the AirPort adapter.  It’s likely the Bluetooth radio (chip) is failing or has failed.  Get it replaced.  There is no “hardware to OS bridge.”  They are called *drivers* and if it was this buggy, you’d see a ton more activity on this issue and  it wouldn’t  last this long.